# Pass argument to directive after rendering

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive.

HTML :

```
    <ul  class="leveringsdag" style="margin-top:20px;" demo-directive ></ul>
    <!-- here I want to pass dat as argument  probably like 

<ul  class="leveringsdag" style="margin-top:20px;" demo-directive data="myData"></ul>
 -->
```

directive :

```
phonecatApp.directive('demoDirective', function($compile) {
    return {
      template: '<div></div>',
      replace: true,

      link: function(scope, element) {
        var el = angular.element('<span/>');

        // Here I want to get json passed as arguments for logic

        var day = ["zondag","maandag" ,"dinsdag", "woensdag" ,"donderdag" , "vrijdag" , "zaterdag"];
            var d = new Date();
            var n = d.getDay(); 
            var temp = "";


        for(i=n ; i<6 ; i++){


             var myString = '<li> <input class="checkleveringsdag" name="leveringsdag" value="2014-10-14" checked=""  type="radio">&nbsp;' + day[i] + '</li>';
             temp += myString;
            }
        for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++){

             var myString = '<li> <input class="checkleveringsdag" name="leveringsdag" value="2014-10-14" checked=""  type="radio">&nbsp;' + day[i] + '</li>';
             temp += myString;
            }
        $compile(temp)(scope);
        element.append(temp);
      }
    }
  });
```

The data i want to get in my directive from controller

Controller :

```
$scope.pickAdelivery = function ( vendor_id ){

                       var  data = $http.get(_BaseURL  ,{headers: {'Accept': 'application/json',
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json' }}).then(function (result) {

                           // console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                           console.log("Success in Wishlist AJAX");

                           console.log(JSON.stringify( result ));

                           $scope.myData = result.data; // this data i waana pass to directive

                        }, function (result) {
                            hideloader();
                           // commonAlert("Error:Please Try again");
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                        })
```

I want to get the data inside my directive to perform my logic . My data is coming from ajax after  function called . But i am unable to get that

Comment: you can pass data name to directive by attribute (like `ngmodel`) then you can watch changing in scope ,and when data will arrive,its will trigger watch inside directive then you can modify dom

Comment: can you please show how ? . Nothing seems working for me

Comment: ok,i will set up plunk,give me a little time)

Comment: ok thanks for being kind . em waiting

Answer (score 0):

to summarize my [thoughts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585850/pass-argument-to-directive-after-rendering?noredirect=1#comment41787192_26585850) here example of directive:

#### directive

```
.directive('demodirective', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
          
        scope:false,// this mean that directive use parent scope!!!!

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                  //get from attribute prop name
                 var scopePropToWatch=attrs.mymodel;

                  //start watching
            scope.$watch(scopePropToWatch,function(newVal,oldval){
                if (newVal!=''&&newVal!=null)
                {
                    $('.insertAfterThis').append('<span>'+newVal+'</span>');
                }
            });                
            },
        template: '<div class="insertAfterThis">Name: <input type="text" /> Address: some adrresss</div>'
      };
    });
```

here working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egm3dh30/3/)

Comment: No . i am looking for something where i get the data of ajax inside my directive . can you please modify the above

Comment: can you please tell me where exaxtly i need to change in my code

Comment: you better not make ajax call inside directive,use [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) to wrap all ajax call stuff,but anyway after makin ajax call from anywhere you just need to set up `$scope.myModel` to trigger your dom modifications

Comment: ok i can change your code a little bit later for clarify answer)

Comment: i am making my ajax inside my controller function.

Comment: did you change anything ?

Comment: not yeat,i will make later,so if you make ajax call in controller , `$scope.myData = result.data;`  in your case you need to watch `$scope.myData` in directive,sorry right now busy ,and as soon as i can i will change your code

Comment: I had some sort of success

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63744/discussion-between-ashish-nautiyal-and-kostia-mololkin).